# Fix packages in broken state when /boot is full

Tags: ubuntu, apt

I noticed that my /boot partition is full (it has only 485M) and apt failed since it cannot install new kernel.

When I do `apt -f install` it fails, when I try to remove one kernel via `apt` or `dpkg` it fails, too.

What is the correct way to handle this? I need to delete at least one kernel so that I can handle the rest via standard `apt` commands.

The server is virtual, I don't have access to the physical machine.

Answer (score 2):

When is the last time you ran `apt autoremove` to clean out old unnecessary packages? This also removes old kernels which you aren't needing anymore. This is the unfortunately neglected but necessary third step after `apt update` and `apt upgrade`.

Comment: Not since the beginning, I know it's the problem, but I cannot run this command now because of the broken state the packages are in. I guess Ubuntu updates the kernel on its own, I didn't do upgrade in a while.

Comment: I would just delete some old kernel files manually and then apt autoremove once there is enough space.